# Core data sync issue

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I want to sync core data between applications which have different Bundle ids but same Team Id. Is it possible to sync between two different bundle id application?

I have make two targets of application and given different bundle id to each.
Please guide me, what should i have to do?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In Xcode you define an entitlements file for iCloud. This has an identifier used for iCloud. If both your apps use the same identifier then they will be able to exchange data.

See "[Configuring your apps iCloud entitlements](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iCloud/iCloud.html)" for the details.

Comment: I've added a link to the documentation. This _is_ how it works.

Comment: Thanks, its working. I tried this before but was not worked.This time i am giving main container directory in cloud URL [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:kCloud_MainDirectory_Url]; Thanks,

Comment: Its syncing in one only direction iphone to ipad but not vice-verse. have you any idea what should be problem?